# Error while running docker image for springboot project

Tags: docker, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a springboot project with spring data jpa

My application.properties looks like

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

It runs without an error when i run with maven "mvn spring-boot:run"

I created a docker image for the project and tried to run it

```
docker run springbootdemo //springbootdemo is the docker image name
```

While running the image i am getting the below error:

```
    2018-07-16 12:12:04.879  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.s.S.SpringBootDemoApplication          : Starting SpringBootDemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on fa7cd1e82e95 with PID 1 (/springDocker.war started by root in /)
2018-07-16 12:12:04.882  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.s.S.SpringBootDemoApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-16 12:12:04.939  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@38cccef: startup date [Mon Jul 16 12:12:04 GMT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-16 12:12:06.145  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$582af4bf] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-16 12:12:06.470  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-07-16 12:12:06.496  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-07-16 12:12:06.496  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.10
2018-07-16 12:12:06.509  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2018-07-16 12:12:06.582  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-07-16 12:12:06.582  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1646 ms
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2018-07-16 12:12:07.030  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-07-16 12:12:07.033  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-16 12:12:07.033  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-16 12:12:07.033  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-16 12:12:07.034  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-16 12:12:07.034  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-16 12:12:07.034  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webMvcMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-16 12:12:07.111  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-07-16 12:12:07.115  WARN 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2018-07-16 12:12:08.224 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:172) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar!/:8.0.11]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar!/:8.0.11]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:862) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar!/:8.0.11]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar!/:8.0.11]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar!/:8.0.11]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar!/:8.0.11]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) [spring-jdbc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: where is your database located? is that inside docker container or on different machine?

Comment: @RohanJMohite I am currently trying to run the image on my local system only.  So i guess they both are on same machine. I am pretty new to docker hence just starting with a POC on my system.

Comment: try with "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://your_machine_IP_address:3306/db1" and it should connect. also please check if firewall restricting 3306 port?

Answer (score 0):

When you are inside of a `Docker` container, the localhost resolves to container IP address. But your Database is not in your application `Docker` container.

So you should change `spring.datasource.url` configuration to a URL that is real database IP address accessible from your application `Docker` container. Change the localhost in `spring.datasource.url` to `Docker` host IP address or your LAN IP address.

Also I think it's better that you specify an environment variable in your `Docker` file that points to the Database IP address and use that in your configuration properties.

Comment: If i put the ip in application.properties i start to get the same error while doing "mvn package" which is required to build new jar for docker image.

Comment: what is your `spring.datasource.url` now ?

Comment: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.1:3306/db1

Comment: Change 172.17.0.1 to your LAN IP address to see if you get the same error.

Comment: Also check to see if you can connect to MySQL with root user outside of localhost. Because AFAIK default MySQL configurations doesn't allow it. are you sure you're getting the exact same error ?